# SharePoint Hosted App: Using Cross Domain call to access list items on Host Web

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, rest, sharepoint-hosted-app

I can use Chrome Advanced REST tools to test out a get list items request on the host web

```
http://mydev/records/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Uber Documents')/Items?$select=Title
```

Ok now I want to use a similar call in SharePoint hosted app that makes a cross domain call to Host Web from Appp Web.

```
  var listName = "Uber Documents";
  executor.executeAsync(
    {

        url: appweburl +
       "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?@target='" +
             hostweburl + "'&$select=Title&$select=Target",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: SuccessHandler,
        error: errorHandler
```

I think my syntax is incorrect as the SuccessHandler fires but I get
       **Could not complete cross-domain call: Bad Request**

Anybody got any tips on how you formulate the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that you have a field called 'Target' in any given list that you might call with this function...

It's probable that your first request in your original post worked just fine, while the second failed because the first didn't attempt to `$select` a field called `Target`

Something to try:

```
var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
function execCrossDomainRequest(listTitle) {
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url:
                appweburl +
                "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/items?$select=Title&@target='" +
                hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        }
    );
}

function successHandler(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.body),
        results = jsonObject.d.results;

    console.log(results);
}

function errorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
    document.getElementById("renderAnnouncements").innerText =
        "Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorMessage;
}
```

Then you can call it with `execCrossDomainRequest('Uber Documents')` and it should log the output into your console.

Comment: sorry I don't even get the failhandler triggered - will test now with my known good url

Comment: Woops, I wasn't inserting the list title or requesting items... should be all fixed now..

Comment: A few typos on my part but I have now tested on Doucments and Uber documents and passed both to renderAnnoucements - all good. Thanks very much. Time to go home! Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Try with this URL

EDIT

```
var url = appweburl +
               "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'&$select=Title,Target"

$.ajax({    

url: url,
type: "GET",    
contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",    
headers: {      "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }, 
success: function (data) {      
        alert('Success')    
     },    
error: function (data) {      
        alert('Failed')    
    } 

});
```

Comment: @vipulKekar I am afraid no change in status - I added the trailing comma.Can you check your syntax.  I can retest my handlers with a known good get web rest call if you need to verify my deployment situation.

Comment: I hope you are creating executor as : var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl); I have edited the answer. Can you post your entire code ?

Comment: Yes creating var executor et.  var url = appweburl +
               "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'&$select=Title,Target";

    executor.executeAsync(
        {

            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                            alert('Sucess')
                 },
            error: errorHandler
        }
    );    sorry about the formatting : daniel at westerdale.biz

Comment: I change the url to var url2 = appweburl +
               "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";  and get the success handler fires... so it has to be the other url . Note AppManifest permissions shows Web and List both set to  read. I don't specify the list at build/publish time.

Comment: I can send you my CrossDomainExec.js if need to verify my code - you can can get me on the above email or via twitter @ westerdaled. I am porting my app sharepoint hosted to on prem provider hosted so test on either. Daniel